# Laço para preencher um input com vários dados - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, testes, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Como fazer um laço para varrer um array e trazer os dados dele um a um e preencher o input?

A imagem ilustra bem o problema...Preciso que o For passe varias vezes pelo método e pegue os dados de la e preencha o input e siga o fluxo normal da automação.

Consigo popular o input com os dados do método:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[1]")).sendKeys(offers());
```

Clico em filtrar os dados para ele popular o `TextArea`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[2]")).click();
```

Seleciono o dado populado no `textArea`:

```
Select selecionapermanenciamulta = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/select")));
        selecionapermanenciamulta.selectByIndex(0);
```

Clico na seta para levar ele para o outro lado:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]")).click();
```

Vetor com os dados:

```
public static String offers (){
            List<String> offrers = new ArrayList<String>();    

            offrers.add ( "dados");
            offrers.add ( "dados");
            offrers.add ( "dados" );

            Collections.shuffle ( offrers );   

            return offrers.get(0);
        }
```

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Não entendi direito a sua dúvida, mas é fazer um `for` que repita esses passos que você colocou?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar como Eu faço este for? Estou com essa dificuldade, sou novo em programação.

Comment: Sobre qual vetor você quer iterar?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar sim felipe, os dados estão no offers(), vou editar a pergunta e colocar ele ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei se eu entendi 100% o que você quer, mas o que me parece que você quer é o seguinte:

```
List<String> testes = new List<String>();
testes.add("teste1");
testes.add("teste2");
testes.add("teste3");
Input textbox = new Input(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[1]")));
Input input1 = new Input(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[17]/td/input[2]")));
Input input2 = new Input(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]")));
Select selecionapermanenciamulta = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[3]/tbody/tr[19]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/select")));
for(String teste: testes){
    textbox.sendKeys(teste);
    input1.click();
    selecionapermanenciamulta.selectByIndex(0);
    input2.click();
}
```

Repare que eu removi o seu método `offers`, já que ele sempre iniciava uma lista de testes e retornava o primeiro elemento dessa lista, depois de embaralha-lá. Imagino que isso resolva o seu problema.

Comment: E essa variável ofertas, Preciso criar ela?  for(String teste: ofertas), esta dando este erro: ofertas cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @PauloRoberto, isso foi erro, na hora esqueci de trocar a variável, deveria ser `testes` ao invés de `ofertas`.

Comment: Não funcionou, Ele passa uma unica vez, e depois o selenium se perde, diz que não localizou um determinado elemento (o input, para onde deveria jogar o próximo valor), mesmo ele estando la.

Comment: Tenta salvar os `findElement` em uma variável, fiz uma edição, vê se resolve.

Comment: ainda dá o mesmo erro!

Comment: Pode colocar o erro aqui?